# Submit two forms with single submit button (JSON)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I have two forms, one on the main page, and another one in iframe. I would like to submit both at the same time with the single submit button.

Here is the one which is on the main page:

```
<form id="loginForm" method="post" action="http://www.example.com/"  >
<div class='hiddenFields'>
<input type="hidden" name="visitor_action" value="login" />
<input type="hidden" name="RET" value="http://www.example.com" />
<input type="hidden" name="site_id" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="2129d6db6941fc2f95b854720f77134f7753d1d7" />
</div>

<div id="sign_up_form">
<label>E-mail: <input type="text" name="username" id="username"/></label>
<div id="actions">
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Sign In" />
</div>
<div id="login-error"></div>
</div>
</form>
```

Ajax/Json part:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#loginForm').ajaxForm({
dataType: 'json',
success: function(data) {
if (data.success) {
window.location.replace("/cabinet/");
} else {
                    $('#login-error').delay(500).fadeIn('slow').html(data.errors.login);
                    $('#login-error').delay(2500).fadeOut('slow');
         }
      }
   });
});
```

And IFRAME:

```
<iframe src="/manager/" id="cabinetz" name="myframe" frameborder="0" width="100%" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

The form within IFRAME has id "**myform**".

How can I modify the json part to submit both forms at the same time?

Comment: see this ,can be helpful :http://nostrongbeliefs.com/form-with-two-submit-buttons-using-html5/

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but try setting up a button with a class, setup submit handlers for each form,  then fire `$.submit()` on both forms.

```
<button class="do-forms">Submit</button>

$( ".do-forms" ).click(function() {

  $("#loginForm").submit(function() { 
   // do ajax call 
  });

  $("#myform").submit(function() { 
   // do ajax call 
  });

  $( "#loginForm" ).submit();
  $( "#myform" ).submit();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Create button and give it **ID**

Jquery Code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#loginForm').ajaxForm({
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.success) {
                window.location.replace("/cabinet/");
            } else {
                $('#login-error').delay(500).fadeIn('slow').html(data.errors.login);
                $('#login-error').delay(2500).fadeOut('slow');
            }
        }
    });

    //ajax form method for second form 

    $('#myform').ajaxForm(function () {
        alert("second form reponse");
    });

    //click event for submitting both form

    $("#testbutton").on('click', function () {
        $('#loginForm').submit();
        $('#myform').submit();
    });
});
```

Here is a <kbd>[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Sh7t3/)</kbd> for same situation but without `iframe`